# Is there a plugin which will allow Gates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was wondering, does a bukkit plugin where you can select an area, and then when right-clicking a sign, a fence/other block fills in the selected area?

So a player could right-click a sign (or button, lever, etc) and a huge fence would retract, allowing the player to get through the otherwise closed-off area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are "fill this area" type plug-ins, but for fence-based gates, there exists a much more "natural" and simpler version:

The plug-in "[PorteCoulissante](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/portecoulissante/)" by Captain_Chaos allows for building redstone-controlled gates out of wooden and iron fences without any client-side modding or using the chat line commands. From the same author, there is also the "[RetractableBridge](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/retractablebridge/)" plug-in available, doing pretty much the same for (horizontally moved) bridges.

It doesn't *fill* an area so much as "moving" the gates in world-space, which means there needs to be enough space above or below the gate for the raised/lowered fence gatter to go to, similar how it works with real portcullises. This can limit some designs. On the other hand, it forces the gate designs to resemble real-world ones, leading to the solution looking "natural" and fitting into the world.

With SpoutCraft and the SpoutClient, both plug-ins support sound effect for moving of the gates and bridges.